# How to apply Matplotlib Basemap's maskoceans() to polygon patches

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I would like to produce a plot of New Zealand with each region colour coded according to some data. However, the shapefiles I have used to produce the image extend beyond the edge of the land and into the ocean. This means that when I colour the polygons they end up colouring portions of the ocean as well. Not the desired response!

The code I am using is:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
lonmax = 180
lonmin = 165
latmax = -33
latmin = -48
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=lonmin,llcrnrlat=latmin,urcrnrlon=lonmax,urcrnrlat=latmax, resolution = 'i')

map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='white')
map.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='white')
map.drawcoastlines()

map.readshapefile('../data/raw/statsnzregional-council-2016-generalised-version-SHP/regional-council-2016-generalised-version', 'regional_council')

ax = plt.gca() # get current axes instance
cm = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0.05, vmax=0.35)

for info, shape in zip(map.regional_council_info, map.regional_council):
    poly = Polygon(shape, facecolor=cm(norm(region_percent[info['REGC2016_N']])),edgecolor='k')
    ax.add_patch(poly)

plt.show()
```

Which produces the below image. This image is very close to what I want but I would like the colouring to stop at the land boundary rather than colouring the ocean as well.

I have looked into Basemap's maskoceans() and believe this is probably the best way to solve this but I don't understand how to apply it to my particular situation (eg, how to access the lat,lons? What is the data array in this case?)

Alternatively is there a way to make the map boundary of New Zealand a hard boundary so only the interior overlap with the polygon patches is printed?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some polygons to mask out the excess areas.
Get the mask files (nz_mask_w.shp, nz_mask_e.shp) here: 
https://github.com/swatchai/cartopy_asean_proj/tree/master/shape_files
And this is the code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import shapefile  # used to read my shapefiles

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
lonmax = 179.95
lonmin = 165
latmax = -33
latmin = -48
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=lonmin, \
              llcrnrlat=latmin, \
              urcrnrlon=lonmax, \
              urcrnrlat=latmax, \
              resolution = 'i')

# this is map theme (change to your need)
map.readshapefile('data/statsnzregional/regional-council-2016-generalised-version', \
                  name='regional_council')

ax = plt.gca()  # get current axes instance

#cm = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('viridis')
#norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=0.05, vmax=0.35)

for info, shape in zip(map.regional_council_info, map.regional_council):
    poly = Polygon(shape, \
                facecolor=cm(norm(int(info['REGC2016']))/100.), \
                edgecolor='k', \
                zorder=1)  
    # original:- facecolor=cm(norm(info['REGC2016']))
    ax.add_patch(poly)


# mask out the excess areas (use files in data sub folder)
sf = shapefile.Reader("data/nz_mask_w")
ss = sf.shapes()
poly1 = Polygon(ss[0].points)

sf = shapefile.Reader("data/nz_mask_e")
ss = sf.shapes()
poly2 = Polygon(ss[0].points)

ax.add_collection( PatchCollection([poly1,poly2], \
                                   zorder=12, \
                                   facecolor='lightblue', \
                                   edgecolor='lightblue' ) )

map.drawcoastlines(color='blue', linewidth=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[image]